# Insert HTML tags like text inside a div

Tags: html, text

I have a div and inside it i have to write some HTML tags, but obviously the browser recognises the tags like an HTML tag. I want that tags like text and not like HTML tags. It is possible to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the `<` and `>` characters in your text, you must use the HTML entities, `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. For example, if you wanted to see

`To make text bold, surround it with <b> and </b>.`,

you would type

`To make text bold, surround it with &lt;b&gt; and &lt;/b&gt;.`

You can find a list of all valid HTML entities at https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref